# CMake with gambit scheme

Tags: makefile, scheme, cmake, gambit

Are there open-source projects out there written in Gambit Scheme that use CMake as the build system? I'd love to have such a CMakeLists.cmake file to use as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posed the question to the gambit mailing list, and while nobody was using cmake, this guy uploaded a working example of a mixed c-and-scheme project, with a makefile:

https://mercure.iro.umontreal.ca/pipermail/gambit-list/2010-November/004662.html

I'd still be very interested to see any instances of using CMake instead of Make.